# Error with threads MongoDB

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose

I have this error:

> 2018-02-08T15:05:25.267-0600 I -        [thread2] pthread_create
>   failed: Resource temporarily unavailable 2018-02-08T15:05:25.267-0600
>   I -        [thread2] failed to create service entry worker thread for
>   10.20.9.217:18465 2018-02-08T15:05:25.272-0600 F -        [conn27232] std::exception::what(): Resource temporarily unavailable Actual
>   exception type: std::system_error

and this is my mongod.service

```
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can the "TaskMax" configuration be responsible?
Did any of you have this error before?

***Y have a router(mongos) and a primary(mongod) in the same server.***

thanks!!!